# SQL query, NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, database-schema

Hi I am evaluating a SQL query with the following schema:
Student(**sid**, name, age, gender, dept, GPA) 
Faculty(**fid**, name, age, office, dept) 
Course(**cid**, name, description) 
Teach(**fid**, **cid**, term) 
Enrollment(**sid**, **cid**, term, grade, final grade)
The question to base query on is: 
Find the students who took at least one course with Tom
The query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student S1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT E1.cid
                  FROM Enrolment E1, Student S2
                  WHERE E1.sid = S2.sid 
                        AND S2.name = 'Tom'
                  MINUS
                  SELECT E2.Cid
                  FROM   E2 Enrollment
                  WHERE  E2.sid = S1.sid)
```

This query is not making sense to me because to me it seems like the NOT EXISTS condition would only select a student when the subquery is empty, and this would only occur in the case when student s1 has taken all the same courses as Tom. However the question is to find the students who took at least one course, not all courses as Tom. Maybe I am interpreting wrong but I could use some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @TomID nvarchar(MAX)
set @TomID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID from Students where Name = 'Tom')

select distinct E1.SID from Enrollment E1 
where E1.SID != @TomID AND E1.CID in
(select distinct E.CID from Enrollment E
where E.SID=@TomID)
```